# Running an event only on browser/tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I know about `window.onbeforeunload`, but that also executes when the user clicks on a link or refreshes the page, while I want my function to only execute when the browser or tab is closed. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only options are `unload` and `onbeforeunload` so I would say the answer to your questions is "no".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload